# Why Angular's reactive form bindings do not require @Input?

Tags: angular

The question arises when I am reading this https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet where you't expect an `@Input()` to be used and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Input()` is used to inform Angular to bind a variable name used in the **component template** to a variable in a **component class**.

In the example in the documentation (I'm talking about this one : https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/reactive-forms/final.eplnkr.html), we can see, in hero-list.component.html :

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

and in hero-detail.component.ts, which defines `<app-hero-detail>`, we can see :

```
@Input() hero: Hero;
```

So, as long as some custom variables are used in template, you still need `@Input()`.

For variables bound in the component code (with reactive form syntax), there is no need to inform Angular to bind anything, it's already done automatically, it has no need of special annotation to understand the binding.

If this is not clear enough, please be more specific by giving a code example, as already asked in comments.